# How to stop autoplay slideshow in opencart 2.1.0.1 version with default theme?

Tags: jquery, slideshow, opencart2.x

I am using opencart version 2.1.0.1 with default theme. I wants to stop autoplay slideshow which display on top of home page.

So how can i stop it. I tried in

"catalog/view/javascript/jquery/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js" script, but didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: edit `catalog/view/theme/default/template/module/carousel.tpl` and remove the autoplay property

Comment: But below javascript code is already commented then how it will work? And also i am using slideshow module so i think these changes should be in catalog/view/theme/default/template/module/slideshow.tpl

Comment: Thanks for your script suggestions. Problem Solved..!